# ¿Cómo puedo crear Variables conforme se presione un botón? (Java)

Tags: java, variables, botón

Pense que podia hacerlo con un For, pero no puedo, lo que intento hacer es una calculadora, puede que no entiendan porque, pero la idea es que cuando se presione el boton de  "+" se cree una variable, y asi poderla sumar con la que se esta mostrando en pantalla, y si el usuario presiona 2 veces el "+" entonces sumarl las 3 variables, y asi sucesivamente:

```
if(jButton1.isSelected() == true){

  for(int i = 0; i <= numbers; i++){ 

    String value(i) = i;

  }

}
```

Si me pueden ayudar seria genial, gracias!

**pd = soy nuevo, asi que si ven codigo un poco raro, es por eso.**

**EDIT:** me piden un ejemplo, asi que intentare ser lo mas claro posible, no estoy seguro si asi se convierte un JLabel a un entero, pero ustedes me entiende:

```
   String Value1 = 0;

   jLabel1 = Integer.parseInt().toString();   

   int Resultado = Value1 + jLabel1;

   LabelPantalla.setText(Resultado);
```

y entonces, si el usuario presiona 2 veces el boton para sumar, y quiere hacer la suma de "5 + 6" entonces seria algo asi:

```
String value1 = 5, value2 = 6;

jLabel1 = Integer.parseInt().toString();

int Resultado = value1 + value2 + jLabel1;

LabelPantalla.setText(Outcome);
```

Mi idea es poner un For, y en ese crear cuantas variables sea necesario, osea, si el usuario quiere sumar 3 terminos, quiero que cada ves que le presione al boton de sumar, se crea una nueva variable con ese numero que puso, y cuando presione el boton de resultado, las variables creadas se sumen. Algo asi.

Comment: Segun yo variable son los de Int, String y esos, tal ves me confundi

Comment: ¿Por que no usas un arreglo? te acetpa hasta 2,147,483,647 valores en teoría.

Comment: Lo que tu quieres hacer es que cada vez que el usuario apreté el botón "+" agregar un componente swing donde el usuario podrá poner el número que desea sumar, si apretó 4 veces el"+" entonces tendrá que poner 4 números a sumar, a eso te refieres?

Comment: exacto, eso es lo que quiero decir